# Length of parametrically defined curve

Tags: multivariable-calculus, parametric, chain-rule, arc-length, trigonometric-integrals

Say I have a curve defined as:
$$
x = a cos^3t\\ 
y = a sin^3t\\ 
0 ≤ t ≤ 2\pi$$

And I wish to find its length.
$$\int_{A}^{B}\{(\frac{dx}{dt})^2 + (\frac{dy}{dt})^2\}^{1/2}$$

Finding $dx/dt$ by way of the chain rule:
$$
x = acos^3t \\
u = cost \\
x = au^3 \\
\frac{dx}{du} = 3au^2 \\
\frac{du}{dt} = -sint
\frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{dx}{du} * \frac{du}{dt} = -3acos^2tsint
$$

Similarly (work omitted for terseness) $\frac{dy}{dt} = 3asin^2tcost$

Plugging into the length formula:

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\{(\frac{dx}{dt})^2 + (\frac{dy}{dt})^2\}^{1/2} = \\
\int_{0}^{2\pi}\{(-3acos^2tsint)^2 + (3asin^2tcost)^2\}^{1/2} = \\
\int_{0}^{2\pi}\{9a^2cos^4tsin^2t + 9a^2sin^4tcos^2t\}^{1/2} = \\
\int_{0}^{2\pi}\{9a^2cos^2tsin^2t(cos^2t + sin^2t)\}^{1/2}$$

Since $cos^2t + sin^2t = 1$ that simplifies to

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sqrt[2]{9a^2cos^2tsin^2t} = \\
\int_{0}^{2\pi}{3a\cos{t}\sin{t}}$$

Since $costsint = \frac{1}{2}sin2t$ the above simplfies further to:
$$\frac{3a}{2}\int_{0}^{2\pi}{sin2t}$$

which integrates as 
$$
\frac{3a}{2} * \left[-cos2t\right]_0^{2\pi}
$$
Since $\cos{4\pi} = 1$ and $\cos{0} = 1$ that expands to $\frac{3a}{2}((-1) + 1)$ resulting in a length of 0, which is.... clearly impossible.

My real question is, could someone please help me identify where I went wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: You didn't evaluate the integral...

Comment: By symmetry, change the upper limit to $\frac{\pi}{2}$ and multiply the resulting value by $4$

Comment: Go a little further. Put the 3a outside the final integral, then what do you have left in the integrand? Rewrite it as sin(2t). Rest is easy.

Comment: Additionally, you cannot naively remove the square root without considering the fact that everything has to be positive...

Comment: Integral actually taken. Sorry for trailing off like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply forgot that 
$$\sqrt{9a^2\cos^2 t\sin^2t}=\lvert3a\sin t\cos t\rvert.$$

You can use that this curve (an *astroid*) has many symmetries: w.r.t. the $x$-axis, the $y$-axis and the *first bissectrix* $y=x$, since 
$$\Bigl(x\bigl(\tfrac\pi2-t\bigr), y\bigl(\tfrac\pi2-t\bigr)\Bigr)=\bigl(x(t),y(t)\bigr)$$
So all you have to do is compute the integral on the interval $\;\bigl[0,\frac\pi4\bigr]$ and multiply the resulting length by $8$.